# Javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat8

I am trying to switch from Tomcat 6 to 8.

JSP File:

```
<h1><c:if test="${#article.category.name != '' && #article.category.name != null}"><s:property value="article.category.name" />: </c:if><s:property value="article.title"></s:property></h1>
```

Exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: file:/help.jsp (line: 75, column:
>   20) "${#article.category.name != '' && #article.category.name !=
>   null}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to
>   parse the expression [${#article.category.name != '' && #article.category.name != null}]

Comment: should it just be article.category.name instead of #article.category.name?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pound sign (#) preceding article.category.name.

This should work for you:

```
<h1><c:if test="${article.category.name != '' && article.category.name != null}"><s:property value="article.category.name" />: </c:if><s:property value="article.title"></s:property></h1>
```